# Copy - Paste rows using MySQL INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains many rows, ordered by the field 'seq'.
I have selected rows 6-9 and I want to copy and paste them on row 3 for example.
For that I'd like to create an SQL query that does the following:

```
INSERT INTO my_table ( seq, field1, field2.... ) 
SELECT seq, field1,field2..
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN ( 234, 233,232 )
```

(id field is the auto increment field that identifies my selected rows).

Now - I managed to duplicate the rows into the table. 
What is missing is to correctly update the 'seq' field in the following manner :

1. In the pasted location (3) my rows should contain the values 3,4,5.
2. All the original rows in that location should be incremented by 3 so that the original row (seq=3) should now become (seq=6) and all rows move 3 rows down the table.

Can this be achieved with an SQL query ?

Comment: I think I would tackle this by copying out to a temporary table and then updating my_table overwriting. This way I would not be messing about with auto increment.

Comment: No, you cannot perform inserts and updates in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger which check for seq, if a sequence exists, it will update sequence numbers above it and will.

```
create table s_sequence 
(seq number(3),
 name varchar2(2000)
);

create or replace trigger s_seq_order
  before insert on s_sequence
  for each row
declare
  seq_exists varchar2(20);
begin
  begin
    select 1 into seq_exists from s_sequence where seq = :new.seq;
  exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
      null;
  end;
  if seq_exists = '1' then
    update s_sequence set seq = seq + 1 where seq >= :new.seq;
  end if;
end;
```

> inserting (seq, name) with (1, 'A') , (2, 'B') .. (5, 'E')

[image]

> now insert (2, 'F')

[image]

But, I am not sure if this is an appropriate way to deal with order. 
but why put any data in table in order ?

**PS : This code tested in  `oracle`.**

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I am trying a different strategy.. Working with 'INSERT INTO' I would like to paste my copied rows, and calculate a 'seq' value for them based on the number of inserted row. Is there an expression I could use when inserting a row that could give a value to each row: 'place_to_insert + number_of_row_in_query' ?  For example - if I am inserting 3 rows in place 5- I'd like the expression to calculate as (5+1),(5+2),(5+3) for each of the rows.

Comment: in my case, you don't nee to worry about how many rows.the trigger works row wise.